# For what purpose may synchronization primitives and containers from Boost library be needed?

Tags: c++, boost, c++17

For what purpose may synchronization primitives and containers from Boost library be needed if the project uses C++ 11/14/17 in which there are already containers and synchronization primitives?

I know that Boost.asio is usually used in work with the network, Boost.spirit - usually for parsing of text. Do you know about the usual purpose of the other parts of Boost?

This question is from the C++ interview.

Comment: There are plenty of boost libraries that haven't been/will never be standardised. Some boost libraries that have now been standardised have additional features that aren't (yet) part of the standard.

Answer (score 2):

Boost is *older* than C++ 11 so many synchronization priminitives were there before they made it to the standard. This was feasible because the OSes already contained thread and synchronization functions so boost could wrap around them.

That said, at this point the C++ standard allows for trivial threading/synchronization. It's adequate for the average C++ developer. In complex sync scenarios you might need some boost-enhanced libraries, or even OS-dependant APIs, for example in Windows, WaitForMultipleObjects().